# In the Films table create a calculated column called NumberBreaks which shows for each film the number of breaks needed

Tags: powerbi, dax

The Films table looks like this

[image]

There is a ComfortBreaks table looking like image

[image]

In the Films table I need to create a calculated column called NumberBreaks which shows for each film the number of breaks needed.  To do this I have to pick out the value of the Breaks column where:

The value of the lower limit in the ComfortBreaks table is less than or equal to this film's running time in minutes
and
The value of the upper limit in the ComfortBreaks table is greater than this film's running time in minutes.

the result should look like the image below

[image]

There cannot be a relationship between the two tables. so this has to be done without creating relationship between them.

I tried lookup function but it showed error:A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code for your custom column. Considering

```
number_of_breaks = 

VAR current_row_run_time_minutes = Films[RunTimeMinutes]

RETURN 
MINX (
    FILTER(
        ComfortBreaks,
        ComfortBreaks[LowerLimit] <= current_row_run_time_minutes
            && ComfortBreaks[UperLimit] > MonthNumber
    ),
    ComfortBreaks[Breaks]
)
```

You can perform your further average calculation on the new custom column now.

Comment: can you please explain 1) what does the filter return? 2) does the filter compare all values in VAR with all values in ComfortBreaks? 3) how does the filter gets compared with ComfortBreaks[Breaks] in MINX function?

Comment: 1. Filter return a table with filtered data from a base table. 2. This is row based operation and there will be single value per row in the VAR and find the break for that single value in the VAR. 3. Finally there will be one single value and you can use any other aggregation to pick the value. Here i just used MINX. But you can use SUM or AVERAGE and result will be same.